# Is CircleCI able to interpret JUnit XML results generated through Gradle without extra plugins?

Tags: gradle, junit, circleci

I have a build.gradle running on CircleCI with the following characteristics:

1. It contains the dependency: `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`
2. It contains normal JUnit test cases.
3. Tests run with commands like `gradle build` or `gradle test`
4. When tests run, JUnit writes their results as XML files in the build/test-results directory. These are files with names like `TEST-*.xml`

However, CircleCI seems to be unable to parse these files. All it shows is a message like 'The following errors were encountered parsing test results:', and, then, a list of all the XML files.

Does anyone know whether it is necessary to generate these test results in a particular format? If so, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't explain, introducing the Gradle Wrapper into the project solved my problem.

For info about the Gradle Wrapper, see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html